# Calculate rolling mean, max, min, std of time series pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to calculate a rolling mean, max, min, and std for specific columns inside a time series pandas dataframe. But I keep getting NaN for the lagged values and I'm not sure how to fix it. My MWE is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# original data
df = pd.DataFrame()
np.random.seed(0)
days = pd.date_range(start='2015-01-01', end='2015-05-01', freq='1D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': days, 'col1': np.random.randn(len(days)), 'col2': 20+np.random.randn(len(days)), 'col3': 50+np.random.randn(len(days))})
df = df.set_index('Date')

print(df.head(10))

def add_lag(dfObj, window):
    cols = ['col2', 'col3']
    for col in cols:
        rolled = dfObj[col].rolling(window)
        lag_mean = rolled.mean().reset_index()#.astype(np.float16)
        lag_max = rolled.max().reset_index()#.astype(np.float16)
        lag_min = rolled.min().reset_index()#.astype(np.float16)
        lag_std = rolled.std().reset_index()#.astype(np.float16)
        dfObj[f'{col}_mean_lag{window}'] = lag_mean[col]
        dfObj[f'{col}_max_lag{window}'] = lag_max[col]
        dfObj[f'{col}_min_lag{window}'] = lag_min[col]
        dfObj[f'{col}_std_lag{window}'] = lag_std[col]

# add lag feature for 1 day, 3 days
add_lag(df, window=1)
add_lag(df, window=3)

print(df.head(10))
print(df.tail(10))
```

Comment: Try adding values: `dfObj[f'{col}_mean_lag{window}'] = lag_mean[col].values`

Comment: Thanks, this works. But like FredMaster's solution below, both `df['col2_std_lag1']` and `df['col3_std_lag1']` columns are filled with `NaN`.

Comment: You cannot have a value other than zero when you are calculating the standard deviation for one value . . . you set the rolling window to 1: `.rolling(window=1)` What did you expect

Answer (score 1):

Just don't do `reset_index()`. Then it works.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# original data
df = pd.DataFrame()
np.random.seed(0)
days = pd.date_range(start='2015-01-01', end='2015-05-01', freq='1D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': days, 'col1': np.random.randn(len(days)), 'col2': 20+np.random.randn(len(days)), 'col3': 50+np.random.randn(len(days))})
df = df.set_index('Date')

print(df.head(10))

def add_lag(dfObj, window):
    cols = ['col2', 'col3']
    for col in cols:
        rolled = dfObj[col].rolling(window)
        lag_mean = rolled.mean()#.reset_index()#.astype(np.float16)
        lag_max = rolled.max()#.reset_index()#.astype(np.float16)
        lag_min = rolled.min()#.reset_index()#.astype(np.float16)
        lag_std = rolled.std()#.reset_index()#.astype(np.float16)
        dfObj[f'{col}_mean_lag{window}'] = lag_mean#[col]
        dfObj[f'{col}_max_lag{window}'] = lag_max#[col]
        dfObj[f'{col}_min_lag{window}'] = lag_min#[col]
        dfObj[f'{col}_std_lag{window}'] = lag_std#[col]



# add lag feature for 1 day, 3 days
add_lag(df, window=1)
add_lag(df, window=3)

print(df.head(10))
print(df.tail(10))
```

Comment: Thanks. When I save the `df` table: `df.to_excel(r'testlag.xlsx', index=True, header=True)`, I see that there are two columns with missing values. Both `df['col2_std_lag1']` and
`df['col3_std_lag1']` columns are filled with NaN values

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you use the rolling function, it creates NaN for the values that it cannot calculate.

For example, consider a single column, col1 = [2, 4, 10, 6], and a rolling window of 2.

- The output of the rolling window will be NaN, 3, 7, 8.
- This is because the rolling average of the first value cannot be calculated since there the window looks at that given index and the previous value, for which there is none.

Then, when you calculate the mean, std, etc you are calculating a series functions without accounting for the NaN. In R, you can usually just do na.rm=T; however, in Python it is recommended that you drop the NaN values, then calculate the series function.